# Page not mobile friendly but sometimes google says it is mobile friendly

Tags: mobile-first-index, mobile-friendly-tool

When I test my site's url using Google Mobile Friendly test tool, sometimes it says Mobile Friendly, but sometimes it says not mobile friendly (Content wider than screen, and Clickable elements too close together).
Here are the results when it says [friendly](https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly?id=-JDc-Jtj53MFDrrL1HTysg), and [not friendly](https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly?id=Dp1vw09CfOuk3VZFIa7UVg). I wonder why?

Comment: After reviewing the question I've concluded it is too specific based on the theme you are using and therefore it is unlikely to help others and therefore has been closed.

Comment: I recommend that you continue to communicate with the developer of the theme and I would strongly advise you test the site with JavaScript disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely caused by JavaScript blocking the render tree. I'm not going to go through all your code but if you look at the bottom, of each source you can see there's a difference in code:

**Rendered correctly:**

`lazyFeaturedImage();</script><iframe style="display: none;"></iframe></body></html>`

**Rendered incorrectly:**

`lazyFeaturedImage();</script></body></html>`

Comment: I test site using Google pagespeed insights. It says, Eliminate render blocking resources". I get a css url, two JS links:(https://thenewspaper.tech/assets/js/lazysizes.min.js?v=300b16f1c14e1537e6b064f464ab33b1) and (https://thenewspaper.tech/assets/js/scripts.min.js?v=6bf8b3435c2c4dcb3b9abe5144d8dbd7). Are uou referring to these JS ? If this is the case, I had asked  theme developer and he said, "this might be related to your slow net connection. All files are needed for theme to work properly". Is this true ? If not, will Googling "Eliminate render-blocking resources" help?

Comment: Looks like didn't load the CSS of your "unfriendly" version (which would kill anything responsive to mobile)

Comment: sorry, what is unfriendly version